# Gerrit Trigger Plugin not listed in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I created a gerrit server and a jenkins server, and I've been following this [Gerrit Trigger Documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/). I went to Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>Manage Plugins, and in all tabs (Updates, Available, Installed) I couldn't find any Gerrit Trigger plugin. Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's your Jenkins version?

Comment: Does your Jenkins instance have internet connectivity? Can it connect to the Jenkins update center?

Comment: @Technext I just installed Jenkins 2.241 with the .war file and thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: @Pankaj yes I believe Jenkins is connected to the internet, but just in case how would I go about checking if my instance of jenkins has internet connectivity?

Comment: Jenkins fetch the plugins from update center https://updates.jenkins.io/; so if you able to see the list of plugins in the available section; that means it is able to reach it. The other way to check connectivity could be via curl or wget that URL from the m/c it is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Jenkins Instance has connectivity to the Internet (means that you able to see plugins under Available tab then the plugin should be there. You can search for it with the name.

In case of no internet connectivity; suppose in some air-gapped env; there are other ways to install the plugin like uploading plugin file under the Advanced tab followed by Jenkins restart.

Comment: Okay thanks! The plugins didn't automatically show up, but when I used the search bar they showed up.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the [official](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/#documentation) Gerrit Trigger Plugin page, at least the *latest* version of the plugin i.e., `2.30.5` requires Jenkins version `2.121.1`

[image]

I am using Jenkins version `2.222.4` and I can see the plugin in `Available` section as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Technext I didn't realize there was a search bar in the 'Available' tab and found the plugin :)